# Samsung Gear 2 app icons

Tags: android, tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, samsung-galaxy-gear

So my Gear app is coming along nicely, but I've run into a bit of a problem with the app icons. I've designed a nice white-outline version of my icon that looks good on the device and fits in with the system apps.

But on the Gear Manager (on the phone), it looks awful, because the background is almost white. Is it possible to specify a different icon for Gear Manager, and if so, how?

Comment: Bonus: could someone with sufficient mojo create a Samsung-Gear tag?

Comment: Assuming you are using the Eclipse IDE, there are 4 seperate folders for holding icons.  You only need to specify the name of the file, and the system will automatically display the most optimized version.  You'll have to create those yourself.  I recommend Photoshop for a PNG-24 (transparent).  If you can't get that, use GIMP.  It's more difficult, but fully functional, and most importantly, free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this can't be done as you can have only one icon for the app. But if that white background  disturbs you make it transparent.